# Changing an exsiting path of Map drive

Tags: dictionary, registry, network-drive

We have changed our file server IP , but most of our users connected their map drive by using the old IP address , so I came to point to change the profile of the users to use the hostname instead of IP but the challenge is most of the users have more than map network drive but all of them pointed to the same fileserver

i have tried some PS command , registry with no luck, i need just replace the IP address with Hostname
thanks in advance

PS examples i have tried

### Enter-PSSession of the remote pc
Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKEY_USERS*\Network*"  | Select RemotePath  then applied the changes

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk –ComputerName hostname | Select SystemName, DeviceID, ProviderName

i have checked the below which is very close to my issue

[How can you replace multiple UNC paths of mapped drives via registry using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430446/how-can-you-replace-multiple-unc-paths-of-mapped-drives-via-registry-using-power)